# how can i add class before all active li

Tags: jquery, css

what i want do add class before active class all LI bellow is something like code will be

say when current class 3 number li then add class 1 and 2 li too

```
<ul id="nav">
      <li class="bar"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li class="bar" ><a href="#"><span>Products</span></a></li>
      <li class="current"><a href="#"><span>Rentals</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Company</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Location</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

same when 5th number li active

```
 <ul id="nav">
          <li class="bar"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
          <li class="bar" ><a href="#"><span>Products</span></a></li>
          <li class="bar" ><a href="#"><span>Rentals</span></a></li>
          <li class="bar" ><a href="#"><span>Company</span></a></li>
          <li class="current"><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Location</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

i trying . if i can make it something then i will keep update here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use try [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

```
$('#nav li.current').prevAll().addClass('bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of prevAll() function of jquery

```
$('#nav li.current').prevAll().addClass('bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#nav li").find(".current").prevAll().addClass('bar');
```

This will add class to all prev. elements

Answer (score 0):

check this [demo](http://jsdo.it/sarfraznawaz/rrmE)

```
//To select all previous elements of `.current` element:
$('.current').prevAll().addClass('bar');
//To select all next elements of `.current` element:
$('.current').nextAll().addClass('bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is tagged jQuery, however here is a pure js method as well which uses `previousElementSibling`

```
var el = document.querySelector('.current').previousElementSibling;
while (el) {
   el.classList.add('bar')
   el = el.previousElementSibling;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/h2hwU/)